# An error is reported when the app is installed on a mobile phone

Tags: android

When I install the APK on a mobile phone, the following error information is displayed: 
failed to find provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices, excepted to find a valid ContentProvider for this anthority.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the problem is caused by the low version of the Firebase SDK.

1. Check whether Google Mobile Services is installed on your phone.
2. Check whether the app depends on the firebase-perf SDK. If yes, upgrade the app to the latest version (19.0.5).